# Anything that I close won't open again

Tags: windows-7, windows

I was currently encountering a problem where when I close a program like Chrome, Firefox, or any application that needs Internet (including Help), won't open anymore when I try to open it again. Not happening in Safe Mode though. I scanned my computer with Malwarebytes and it didn't detect any malware or malicious programs in my computer. It only happens in Normal Mode. It's my first time experiencing this error.

Comment: I would suggest running Process Monitor - https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon ,do you even see a "Process Start" operation for the failed launch?  If so, what happens to that process if you scroll down following the PID for it?  I assume it exits?  Does the Exit status code of the "Process Exit" event operation help?

Comment: Okay I'll try it. ; No, I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: That was fast, do you even see the "Process Create" operation from the launching process. E.g. if you launch Firefox.exe then typically Explorer.exe is the parent and you see something like:
`11:13:46.2261104 Explorer.EXE 4212 18120 Process Create C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe SUCCESS PID: 16936,`

Comment: Oh, am I going to use Process Monitor first?

Comment: Yes. That is the recommendation.

Comment: I'm seeing `6:53:21.2543906 PM Explorer.EXE 1392 CreateFile C:\Program Files (x86)\ ... \ chrome.exe SUCCESS Desired Access: ..........`. It opened at that time, but I can't close my chrome because it may not open again.

Comment: Okay, It's solved. I went to Safe Mode, I was checking the Startup Folder in the Registry (HKU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run), and something in there was starting everytime I run, it was like some kind of a virus that is undetectable by Malwarebytes, it's starting everytime I run in Normal Mode, but is restricted in Safe Mode. The key was named 'WebSearchHelper', I deleted it; back to Normal Mode, open Chrome, Close, then Reopen, then it's reopening again. Thanks for the help anyways, but I have solved my problem.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem then the right thing to do is writing an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, It's solved. I went to Safe Mode, I was checking the Startup Folder in the Registry (`HKU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`), and something in there was starting everytime I run, it was like some kind of a virus that is undetectable by Malwarebytes, it's starting everytime I run in Normal Mode, but is restricted in Safe Mode. The key was named `WebSearchHelper`, I deleted it; back to Normal Mode, open Chrome, Close, then Reopen, then it's reopening again. Thanks for the help anyways.